Simply moving the HTML file and folder of a "Webpage, Complete" copy of a webpage breaks the page in Linux, but not Windows
Moving them to a different directory, that is. After the move, the HTML file can't see the corresponding folder. In contrast, Windows discreetly recognizes "Webpage, Complete" files and even if you try to move just the HTML file to a different directory, the folder automatically goes with it!

Can you share an example?
